# Android how to set longtimeclick on listview

Tags: android, listview

Please advise on how to set a onLongtimeclicklistner with a contextmenu on listview?

And how to add items to the contextmenu?

Can someone tell me the steps or any advice on how to carry this out efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e("Log", "Item clicked " + position);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry ,  I forgot that I want a menu when long click happened

Comment: I quess you want a contextual menu. There are tons of tutorials for that on the internet. Try one...

Answer (score 1):

```
listView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry , I forgot that I want a menu when long click happened